# "Similar questions" scrolls down and covers other links

Tags: bug, design

"Similar questions" should not move with the scrolling.
[image]

I guess it is also true for other stackechange sites. I have asked a question. FF 11.0, win 7.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What were you doing when this happened? Browser/OS? Doesn't happen to me

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Can't repro in Chrome beta/FF12b.

Comment: I cannot repro in chrome as well.

Comment: I'm having this [problem as well](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/q/1142/4262) with the latest Chrome version (23.0.1271.64).

Comment: Copy-pasting my comment on reproducibility: I can reproduce the problem if I take the text in this meta post (first paragraph is enough) and begin typing it manually in a new meta post. If I wait a bit (I was actually switching to other tabs and then came back later) with my cursor in the question body text box, the similar questions list will appear on the side. Scroll down, and the text will cover the bottom of the page.