# Similar questions in sidebar overlay rest of page when scrolling

Tags: bug, design, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Similar questions” scrolls down and covers other links](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/878/similar-questions-scrolls-down-and-covers-other-links)

I ran into this today when asking a question on UX.SE. What I was seeing was that the similar questions that appear in the sidebar will does will cover the rest of the page when I scroll down. I'm seeing this on the UX.SE Meta as well.

When I do scroll downwards, that list stays static on the page while everything else will move upwards. I'm using Google Chrome version <s>22.0.1229.94</s> 23.0.1271.64 (the current latest version) on Mac OS X.

Here is a screenshot on the main site:
[image: Similar questions list overlaying page]

And another on Meta:

[image: Similar questions list overlaying page]

Comment: I cannot repro this - can you link to a specific post exhibiting the issue?

Comment: Duplicate of [another question](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/q/878/4262) from April 2012.

Comment: @NickCraver I can reproduce the problem if I take the text in this meta post (first paragraph is enough) and begin typing it manually in a new meta post. If I wait a bit (I was actually switching to other tabs and then came back later) with my cursor in the question body text box, the similar questions list will appear on the side. Scroll down, and the text will cover the bottom of the page.